# "Paradigms of AI Programming" Can I run examples from this book in Racket programming language

Tags: clojure, lisp, artificial-intelligence, racket

I have acquired legendary book: "Paradigms of AI Programming" [PAIP](http://norvig.com/Lisp-retro.html)
Will Racket programming language run examples from this book. Will Clojure do?
Which language to choose in order to keep up easily with examples?

Comment: Great book; good for you on learning a new language.  Go for it.  Only you can decide if it's worth it.

Comment: "will it run?" Is not opinion based question!!!!

Comment: @PaulLeyton It's not opinion based, but it's not really a specific technical question that's a great fit for StackOverflow (and one you could test very quickly).  Scheme (and Racket) and Common Lisp are very different languages.  Very little of the code in PAIP will run without modification in Racket.  However, much of the code will not require *too much* modification.  It you just wan to use PAIP code, grab a free Common Lisp implementation.  If you want to learn Racket and some AI techniques, and already understand Common Lisp, then translating PAIP code into Racket might be a good exercise.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor, that's my point.

Comment: Anyway, I have got the answer. Sad that SO has such strict rules, but in other hand good quality. Thank you both!!

Comment: The code in PAIP wil not run as-is. It is straight forward to port the code to Racket though - especially if you know Racket in advance. If you don't know Common Lisp nor Racket in advance, find a Common Lisp to use with the book.